# What is the difference between URLS with hashtags and hashtags with exclamation marks

Tags: seo, url

What is difference SEO differencence between:

1. `/index.php#mystate`
2. `/index.php#`**!**`mystate`

Comment: The difference in what aspect? In SEO? Please be more precise.

Answer (score 6):

The fragment identifier (when dealing with the URI of an HTML document) is supposed to be used to link to specific parts of a page. It isn't sent to the server.

In the last few years it has been used as a [hack to maintain state information](http://blog.benward.me/post/3231388630) in websites that make heavy use of Ajax.

The use of a fragment identifier starting with a `!` character is a [further hack](http://isolani.co.uk/blog/javascript/BreakingTheWebWithHashBangs) on top of this to tell Google how to generate a real URI for indexing purposes.

The introduction of [pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#The_pushState%28%29.c2.a0method) eliminates the need for these hacks in modern browsers.

For browsers that don't support `pushState` some people take the approach of falling back to the hashbang hack, while others (such as [GitHub](https://github.com/blog/760-the-tree-slider)) fall back to normal links (instead of using Ajax for major content changes [in browsers that don't support `pushState`](http://caniuse.com/#search=pushstate)).

Comment: The "it isn't sent to the server" is often overlooked. That means no edge cdn/performance reverse proxy gets to see those fragments.

Answer (score 0):

The exclamation point, eliminates the case of an empty hash like `example.com/index.php#` which would make the page scroll to the top.